# Can a breakpoint be set for EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

Just as you can set a breakpoint for `objc_exception_throw`, is there an equivalent for  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

Comment: If you're running the program in a debugger, it should stop automatically when you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: You are right.  You have to first bring up the debugger window and you'll see a function in your code.  Click it to reveal the line where the exception is being thrown.  I was always looking at the code window, which won't show anything until you do the above.

Comment: The only downside is that, half the time, the current instruction is somewhere in the framework. But the only remedy for that is better big tracking (contract assertions and stuff)

Answer (score -1):

EXC_ BAD_ ACCESS is an exception (EXCeption_ BAD_ ACCESS). If you set a breakpoint on objc_exception_throw, you'll get those. You might want to look at NSZombieEnabled, as you're probably trying to access a dealloc'd object.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS can be caused in many ways that have nothing to do with objective-c exceptions.